# SQL query not returning data from where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

using MS SQL server 2008.

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM #PreModuleAllData WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE (@Country   != 'DEFAULT' AND @Country   != '' AND([Language] = @Country ))
OR    (@UserType  != 'DEFAULT' AND @UserType  != '' AND([UserType] = @UserType ))
OR    (@Group     != 'DEFAULT' AND @Group     != '' AND([Company] = @Group ))
OR    (@CodeUsage != 'DEFAULT' AND @CodeUsage != '' AND([User Code]= @CodeUsage ))
```

The plan was to return all data if any of the parameters where set to '' or default.
if a paramter was used it should return based on that particular where clause.

For example if the parameter @country is set to a language i.e english the query returns data.

But if all params are set to default nothing is returned, but i need all records to return, I have a feeling the logic is missing something very simple but my eyes cant see why.

Any clues?

Comment: Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) might be a worthwhile read for you, but may not address your actual problem here.

Comment: yes tha plan was to use dynamic search but i had advise that using a where clause condition was the bst way to go as there was no need for overcomplexity....apparantly haha

Comment: @StevenSmith: Your approach is correct, you just mixed conditions bit wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM #PreModuleAllData WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE (@Country   = 'DEFAULT' OR @Country   = '' OR ([Language] = @Country ))
AND   (@UserType  = 'DEFAULT' OR @UserType  = '' OR ([UserType] = @UserType ))
AND   (@Group     = 'DEFAULT' OR @Group     = '' OR ([Company] = @Group ))
AND    (@CodeUsage = 'DEFAULT' OR @CodeUsage = '' OR ([User Code]= @CodeUsage ))
```

Comment: KNEW IT!!! my god i knew the logic was the cause and it was a mixup of what operators! since i didnt want them to = to the values i was using the AND operator and forgot about that final layer logic....thanks for that slap in the face haha! knew it was a simple fix

Answer (score 0):

You need a boolean condition in your where clause:

```
WHERE ((@Country = 'DEFAULT') OR @Country!= 'DEFAULT' AND @Country != '' AND([Language] = @Country ))
AND
```

if the parameter country is not `default`, it will apply that condition. otherwise if the paremeter is default then the second condition will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

you have to re-write the logic as below

```
SELECT * FROM #PreModuleAllData WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE (@Country   = 'DEFAULT' OR @Country   = '' OR (@Country NOT IN ('DEFAULT','') AND [Language] = @Country ))
OR    (@UserType  = 'DEFAULT' OR @UserType  = '' OR (@UserType NOT IN ('DEFAULT','') AND [UserType] = @UserType ))
OR    (@Group     = 'DEFAULT' OR @Group     = '' OR (@Group NOT IN ('DEFAULT','') AND [Company] = @Group ))
OR    (@CodeUsage = 'DEFAULT' OR @CodeUsage = '' OR (@CodeUsage NOT IN ('DEFAULT','') AND [User Code]= @CodeUsage ))
```